# Node.js http post request with basic authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I can make this work with axios but as I want to do this with default http module for some reasons

Here is the code

```
var express = require("express");
const http = require('https');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
    var username = 'username';
    var password = 'password';
    var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

const data = JSON.stringify({
    campaign_id: 'all',
    start_date: '01/01/2010',
    end_date: '05/31/2030',
    return_type: 'caller_view',
    criteria: {
        phone: 98855964562
    }
});

var hostName = "https://staging.crm.com";
var path = "/api/v1/caller_find";

const options = {
    hostName: hostName,
    path: path,
    port: 3000,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': auth,
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};
const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('response is ' + res);
});

req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error is ' + error);
  });
});
```

But it is throwing exception

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Comment: Are you trying to run this locally, or via an HTTP call to your lambda deployment?  Can you please post more information, EG your API Gateway config, and what you're doing that generates the above error?  At first glance it doesn't look to me like you're _listening_ to port 443, just 3000.

Comment: Are you working behind corporate proxy?

Comment: @MattMorgan I have updated the question, leave out the AWS lambda part just need the solution for node.js project.

Comment: Hi @MegaMind, did my answer help at all?

Comment: Did you try  `'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }` ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're providing the wrong `options` object (perhaps copied over from axios). The Node.js HTTP module takes `host` or `hostname` in options, while you're providing `hostName`.

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: This was not the case, I have tried with both and still got this error Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Comment: Use the correct options, 'host' or 'hostname'. 

ENOTFOUND indicates the domain name you're trying to connect to can't be found. Assuming https://staging.crm.com is the real domain, I can confirm I can't connect to it either, indicating it's not available over the public internet.

Since it's a staging server, maybe you need to connect over a VPN, proxy, or something?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Any reason why you need your application to listen? I'm assuming the application you're posting to is hosted somewhere else, as you're attempting to listen to port 3000 while also making the request to an application on port 3000. If each application is on a different host, this should be fine. Nonetheless, you've at least got 3 issues here.

1) Your options object is incorrect. You're using `hostName` when it should be `hostname`. This is why you get the `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443` error; the options object for the `https.request()` method defaults hostname to localhost and port to 443.

2) Also, you never write your `data` object contents to the request stream.

3) Finally, you should listen to the `data` event to get the response back and write it to the console. I've updated your code as shown below:

```
var express = require("express");
const http = require('https');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
  var username = 'username';
  var password = 'password';
  var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

  const data = JSON.stringify({
      campaign_id: 'all',
      start_date: '01/01/2010',
      end_date: '05/31/2030',
      return_type: 'caller_view',
      criteria: {
          phone: 98855964562
      }
  });

  var hostName = "https://staging.crm.com";
  var path = "/api/v1/caller_find";

  const options = {
      hostname: hostName,
      path: path,
      port: 3000,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': auth,
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
      }
  };

  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error is ' + error);
  });

  req.write(data);
  req.end();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot move your express application to AWS Lambda as is. There are tools such as [claudia](https://claudiajs.com/) which can help you move the app to lambda and api gateway.

In your case, you can modify your code AWS Lambda as below

```
const http = require('https');

exports.myHandler = function (event, context, callback) {
var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

const data = JSON.stringify({
    campaign_id: 'all',
    start_date: '01/01/2010',
    end_date: '05/31/2030',
    return_type: 'caller_view',
    criteria: {
        phone: 98855964562
    }
});

var hostName = "https://staging.crm.com";
var path = "/api/v1/caller_find";

const options = {
    hostName: hostName,
    path: path,
    port: 3000,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': auth,
        'Content-Length': data.length
    }
};
const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('response is ' + res);
    callback(null, res);

});

req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error is ' + error);
    callback(error);
});
}
```

You have to invoke your lambda via API Gateway or via other AWS resources such as Alexa Skill Kit etc.

**EDIT**

You may try passing auth options as specified @ https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md#http-authentication

Comment: I know how to make it execute in lambda, problem is with http request. Request itself is not being executed, for simplicity sake just make it execute it in node.js.

Comment: Updated answer.